# Creating an Empty Format Parameter in PHP to hide the output

Tags: php, api, calendar

So I'm new to PHP and write bad code. I am trying to format a calendar to show the entries as list entries. Furthermore, if an event time was entered at 12 AM, I am trying to hide that outputted value. Here is the tutorial that I am using https://spunmonkey.com/display-contents-google-calendar-php/.

Here is the code that is from the tutorial:

```
     $eventdate = new DateTime($eventDateStr,$timezone);
     $newmonth = $eventdate->format("M");
     $newday = $eventdate->format("j");
     $newtime = $eventdate->format("g");
     $newtimeAM = $eventdate->format("A");
```

Here is what I am trying to do and my horribly written code (this if for the newtime div:

```
    <?php
         if ( $newtime="12" && $newtimeAM="AM") {
                echo $eventdate->format("");
            }  else {
                echo $newtime;


            }
        ?>
```

I have written the same if statement for $newtimeAM. My questions are:

1. Can I use the  if statement to set the value to the outputted string, (like $newtime="12")?
2. Can I use the format parameter to return an empty string, as to hide the values if the conditions are met?

Right now, it does display the calendar entry, but not with the time. For example, there is an entry that starts at 2 PM that I want the calendar to show, but it's not showing. Also, what references that anyone give to learn PHP online? I know w3 is pretty awesome and well as php.net.

Comment: `if ( $newtime="12" && $newtimeAM="AM")` you realize what this does right? It "assigns" instead of "comparing". So what you have now, will "always" be that, instead of comparing those two values.

Comment: Yeah that was dumb of me, and thanks for marking this as duplicate to a better question and answer! I can reference that now so much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try fixing your if statement. One = assigns, two == checks!

`if ( $newtime == "12" && $newtimeAM == "AM") {`

The way your code is, you SET these vars, so nothing will output each time!

Comment: Nice that makes alot of sense. I fixed the out and the it should now be outputting correctly. Thanks for your  quick and easy response!

Comment: No problems, and all the best!

Comment: Can you mark as correct answer then please? :-)

Comment: Also, why not remove the first if, and change the if statement to `if ( $newtime != "12" || $newtimeAM != "AM") {` , that way if true echo, and there is no else, so no need to echo nothing!